# Selenium can't find text when there is text

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    x = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text()[0]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have this error when i try to get some text into a variable and the weird thing is that there is a string there so? Heres the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui as pay
import time

PATH = r"C:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


driver.get("https://emat4.dk/menu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ImageButton_UNILogin").click()
time.sleep(1)
pay.write("noah4273")
pay.press("Enter")
time.sleep(1)
pay.write("hejmeddig")
pay.press("Enter")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ImageButton_Tabeltræning").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton_StartTabel").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton_Let").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("nrknap").click()
x = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text()[0]
y = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text()[4]

idk = int(x) * int(y)
pay.write(idk)
pay.press("Enter")
```

The erorr is at **x =** and **y = **

Also this is the html thing thing

```
<label id="Label_Spg" style="font-size: 48pt; -moz-user-select: -moz-none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;">10 • 4</label>
```

Comment: `text` is a property, not a function.

Comment: Can you share a page link? Or at least the entire HTML code

Comment: <label id="Label_Spg" style="font-size: 48pt; -moz-user-select: -moz-none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;">10 • 4</label>

Comment: Is there only 1 element where `id="Label_Spg"`?

Answer (score 2):

`text` is a string attribute of the node, so you just need `text` instead of `text()`

Comment: New error: File "c:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\app.py", line 22, in <module> x = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg")[0].text() TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Ok, get rid of the `[0]` then. `find_element_by_id` returns a scalar. (Also, your error message says you still have `text()` with parenthesis.)

Comment: I have changed the text() i just took the message i have typed where i haden't changed it

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text()` is a string (not an array), so appending `[0]` or what have you makes no sense. I expect you are instead looking for:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg")[0].text
y = driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg")[4].text
```

I was incorrect about your goal. For your current error, `driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ImageButton_UNILogin").click()` is not finding any element. I suspect you need to wait for the element before attempting to interact with it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyautogui as pay
import time

PATH = r"C:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


element = driver.get("https://emat4.dk/menu.aspx")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ImageButton_UNILogin")))

element.click();
```

Comment: New error:

  File "c:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    x = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg")[0].text()
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You need to adjust it to `driver.find_elements_by_id()` -- notice the `s` at the end of find_elements.

Comment: New error:   File "c:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\app.py", line 23, in <module>
    y = driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg")[4].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the index doesn't exist? So it can't find any text

Comment: Yes. The reason that happens is because there is only one element on the page with `id = "Label_Spg"`. That element's text is passed to `x`.

You are correct, the index doesn't exist because that selector only matches one element on the page. If you can point me to which element you are trying to grab with `y = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text()[4]`, I think we are close to working.

Comment: For clarity: it means that the array `driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg")` does not have any member with index `[4]`. Not that a certain element has no text.

Comment: C. Peck `<label id="Label_Spg" style="font-size: 48pt; -moz-user-select: -moz-none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;">10 • 4</label>` I'm trying to get the first and last number from the string 10 • 4

Comment: What is returned by `driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text`? Also worth trying `driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Comment: When you say return do you mean print it out?

Comment: Yes, just. try it where you have the "Label_Spg" element defined in your code, and see if what prints makes sense.

Comment: So now i get like alot of errors i think but its to much to send?

Comment: Please share, at least the most relevant parts if you can

Comment: Don't know what you exactly mean so i just made a pastebin https://pastebin.com/bRGSBT0s

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you want.

```
text = driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg").text
x = text[0]
y = text[-1]
```

Explanation:
`driver.find_element_by_id("Label_Spg")` returns a web element
applying `.text` on it retrieves that web element text. It's a string.
Now, getting the first and last character of the string is done as shown here

Comment: error again..   File "c:\Users\noah4273\Downloads\Python\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    text = driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: You did not use the code I posted! I use `find_element_by_id` here, not `find_elements_by_id`

Comment: Well yes i do. text = driver.find_elements_by_id("Label_Spg").text
x = text[0]
y = text[-1]

Comment: You have just indicated you used `find_elements_by_id` -- the suggestion is to use `find_element_by_id` -- notice the change from `elements` to `element`